# Installing gvim on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

I'm trying to install gvim on WSL (under windows 10) and use [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net) as my X server.

Bash informed me that:

```
 Command 'gvim' not found, but can be installed with:

 sudo apt install vim
```

Which I did and vim was installed but not gvim. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to install the latest version of gvim on WSL

Comment: Maybe this will help https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/using-wsl-and-mobaxterm-to-create-a-linux-dev-environment-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had truncated the list of commands suggested by apt. I wasn't sure how apt determines the list of packages it suggests.

When I ran:

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```

gvim did install and did display the expected file contents using a window created by MobaXterm.

While gvim appeared to be working based on my limited testing so far it did display a series of messages in the terminal window:

```
 (gvim:1869): dconf-WARNING **: 07:14:18.972: failed to 
commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process 
“dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
```

After I installed dbus-x11:

```
 sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

The issue was resolved.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have WSL in front of me at the moment, but going on the assumption that you're using the Ubuntu environment atop WSL, I tried to replicate your condition on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM here:

```
$ gvim
Command 'gvim' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install vim       
sudo apt install vim-gtk3  
sudo apt install vim-tiny  
sudo apt install neovim-qt 
sudo apt install vim-athena
sudo apt install vim-gtk   
sudo apt install vim-nox
```

Did you trim the other outputs from that command, or does the command truly only tell you about the `vim` package under WSL?

APT is *guessing* here, based on the command name you tried, not prescribing. Some of those options will get you something like what you're expecting, and some won't; you're expected to be able to make the distinction. Of the options, I'd recommend `vim-gtk3`, but another might please you better.